# Suggestion for missing reputation on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvotes, reputation-history

Sometimes I lose some reputation, for example I have 814, the next day it becomes 812, and some days later it becomes 810.

I check the Reputation page in my profile and I do not discover why I lost those points. I suppose, for example, I may edit a question and get +2 and this question is deleted now.

Why not add some details about these missing points, e.g.

- "-2 because the question that you edited is deleted now"; or
- "-10 because someone cancelled their up vote".

Comment: Doesn't that already happen?

Comment: Yup, although for the longer written version you need to hover the mouse over the short label next to the score change, it is displayed as a tooltip.